# statements about linear optimization (linear programing), true or false?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoEQs.png)

> For a linear optimization problem, one of the following statements is
> false. Mark the false statement.
>
> Solution $1$: Multiple degenerate basic solutions may correspond to the
> same vertex of the feasible region.
>
> Solution $2$: In each feasible basic solution, there exists at least one
> feasible direction.
>
> Solution $3$: Any feasible direction in a feasible basic solution can be
> written as a linear combination of the basic directions.
>
> Solution $4$: If the problem contains only equality constraints, the
> problem is either infeasible, unbounded or has exactly one feasible
> solution.

Question1: I've marked solution 4 as the false one, but I was wrong. I guess now for $Ax=b$, the result either be no solution, only one solution, and infinite solutions. And they correspond to the optimization problem being infeasible, unbounded, or has exactly one feasible solution. Am I right with Question $1$? If not, please explain.

Question2: I wonder solution $2$ would be the false statement as a simple counter example can be given such that the feasible region only contains a point. In that case, that point would be a feasible basic solution, and there's no feasible directions at all. Am I right with question $2$? If not, please explain. If so, can other more general cases be given besides that the feasible region contains only a point?

Question3: My intuition tells me solution 3 is true. But I don't know how to prove it. Please prove or explain why. If solution $3$ is false, also explain.

PS: I can confirm that solution $1$ is true, no explanation needed on that one. But for completeness, compact explanation is also welcomed.

Comment: Yes, in $x\geq0, -x\geq0$, the point $x=0$ is feasible basic and has no feasible directions.

Comment: can more general case be found besides that feasible region contains only one point?

Comment: In an LP, the feasible set is convex. If it had at least two points, then the interval between them is feasible. That would give you are feasible direction.

Comment: Ok, so you are suggesting the feasible region contains one point is the only counter-case of solution 2? It make sense.

Comment: With (4), do they call "unbounded" a problem where the feasible set is unbounded, or a problem where there is no optimum? I suppose, if they are saying that only one is false, that they mean that the feasible set is unbounded.

Comment: I guess you are right. There is some ambiguity here. If "unbounded" means the feasible set is unbounded, solution 4 is true. If it means "no optimum", I can give a counter example to show it is false: min $x_1$ subject to $x_1=1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. There are infinite feasible solution $(1,x_2)$, but the optimum value of the optimization problem is still bounded, which is 1